# how do I change the default background and toolbox ui of workspace using google blockly library in android

Tags: java, android, xml, blockly

I am using google blockly library for Android. I have read the documentation and configure the blockly library for Android. But I can not change the default background of the workspace as well as the alignment and the design of the toolbox which is on the left side of the workspace. Here is the screenshot of my
[default workspace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G2x3u.png)

I have to change the following portion of the background and the toolbox [need to change to red-mark area](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f6GY2.png)

To change the background I have tried the following code in my java file where onCreateContentView called

```
{
 View root = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.turtle_content, null);
        decorView=root;
        mTurtleWebview = (WebView) root.findViewById(R.id.turtle_runtime);
        mTurtleWebview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mTurtleWebview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            WebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);
        }
        mTurtleWebview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/turtle/turtle.html");
           root.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.black));
        return root;
}
```

using root.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.black)); the background black color set but not replaced.I also want to remove the black dots from the background.

To change to toolbox icon I've tried to change the code in assert>turtle>toolbox_basic.xml file using icon="someValue" format.

Probably the code icon="\turtle\start.png" worked for the ios but I have to change for Android.

I need to know how to do these change for android using a blockly library.

Comment: Ios documentation to change the toolbox ui- https://developers.google.com/blockly/guides/configure/ios/toolbox#categories

Comment: The iOS does things very differently than Android. We don't have an easy solution for this on Android, right now. See discussion on our mailing list: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/blockly/CvcHpS5v9bA